# Create Ef Core Migration-Script manually

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Due to my current project structure where I need to handle many database-views I would like to write the Ef-Core Migration-Classes manually.

We are using the code-first-approach.

I know frameworks like the php [Phinx](https://phinx.org/) where I can simply create migration files manually.

Is this also possible with ef core, without using `database ef migrations add`?

## Update

I tried to create the migration file manually, but then it isn't executed on `context.Database.Migrate()`.
Is that because of the missing `.Designer`-file or the `Snapshot`-File that is not changed?

Do I really need the Snapshot and Designer files? I guess the migration-system tracks executed migrations within the history database table?

## Update 2

I changed from `EF-Migrations` to `FluentMigrator`. This module solves all my problems.

Comment: Have not tried it, but don't see why its not possible.  All `dotnet ef migrations add` does is add a generated class to your project that inherits from `Migration` and has a timestamp added to the filename to allow ordering of the migrations.  My guess is you could create a class manually that inherits from `Migration`, overrides methods `Up` and `Down` and has a timestamp in the name.  When the migration is run, this is recorded in the database so the app knows what migrations have been run.  Alternatively, generate migration normally, then remove & replace existing code in `Up` and `Down`.

Comment: @Neil W many thanks for your reply. What is with the additional created Files like ```ContextModelSnapshot.cs``` and ```*.Designer.cs``` ?

Comment: I don't have a `*.designer.cs` file.  Not sure that applies for Code-First.  The `ContextModelSnapshot.cs` is a full representation of your entity model as a result of the last migration created.  It means that when you make changes to classes, the migration engine can compare current class structure vs the snapshot to determine what has changed and build an appropriate migration to deliver those changes.  The Model Snapshot will be updated after each Migration is created so it always represents the full state of the model as of the latest migration.